# Buildroot packages summary

Tags: buildroot

I have built Embedded system image using buildroot. I want to know what all packages built for the rootfs. Buildroot will create any file with the summary of packages built and their versions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try: `make legal-info` and look in `output/legal-info` for the `manifest.csv`

Answer (score 2):

You can also try `make show-info`.